# Clicking on link freezes the app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, html-parsing, tttattributedlabel

I'm using [Xamarin.TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/colbylwilliams/Xamarin.TTTAttributedLabel) to parse HTML in xamarin.ios app.
Most of the times, whenever I click on the link it freezes the app. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.
I'm using **Label** inside **UIView** **-->** **ScrollView**. My scrollview doesn't have any tap gesture.
This doesn't happen on simulator. Only on physical device.

```
View.AddSubview (scrollView)
TTTAttributedLabel lbl = new TTTAttributedLabel();
lbl.SetText(attributedString, 15f);
lbl.Lines = 0;
lbl.EnabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link | NSTextCheckingType.PhoneNumber;
lbl.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
lbl.Delegate = new TTTHTMLLabelDelegate(this);
lbl.Frame = new CGRect (15, 0, Common.screenWidth - 30, 20);
lbl.SizeToFit();
view2.AddSubview(lbl);
scrollView.AddSubview(view2);



//Delegate code
public override void DidSelectLinkWithURL(TTTAttributedLabel label, NSUrl url)
        {
            if (url != null)
            {
                var PageUrl = url.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PageUrl))
                {
                    if (PageUrl.StartsWith("mailto"))
                    {
                        //code to open email app
                    }
                    else if (PageUrl.StartsWith("tel"))
                    {
                       //code to open phone app

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //for <a> links
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

UPDATED with sample code.
I have observed one more thing, `DidSelectLinkWithURL` not get called when app freezes.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but no luck , can you provide a  simple demo to us ?

Comment: Hi @ColeXia-MSFT, sorry for late reply. I have added the code sample. Does that looks fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store your variable

```
public class YourClass
{
TTTAttributedLabel lbl;

 ViewDidLoad()
 {
       View.AddSubview (scrollView)
       lbl = new TTTAttributedLabel();
       lbl.SetText(attributedString, 15f);
       lbl.Lines = 0;
       lbl.EnabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link | 
       NSTextCheckingType.PhoneNumber;
       lbl.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
       lbl.Delegate = new TTTHTMLLabelDelegate(this);
       lbl.Frame = new CGRect (15, 0, Common.screenWidth - 30, 20);
       lbl.SizeToFit();
       view2.AddSubview(lbl);
       scrollView.AddSubview(view2);
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks @nikita. Last week, I solved the issue by declaring label at class level as you suggested. Initializing inside ViewDidLoad() didn't work for me. So I initialized inside constructor, which fixed the issue for me. One more thing, if you have an array of TTTAttributedLabel then you have to initialize **single element**. Like `lbl[i] = new TTTAttributedLabel();` Just writing `lbl = new TTTAttributedLabel[SIZE]` won't work.

Comment: If you initialize array with [size] all elements will get its default value. Thats why you should initialize every element